# Parameterized stored procedure union all which is conditional with left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, conditional-statements, union-all

I want to do, I think, a `UNION ALL` query so I can return the results from my order table based on the manufacturer id entered in a search field.
Order links to > OrderItem which then can be linked to Product.

I have manually typed up the query, and it works but I'm having trouble making it conditional in my stored procedure.

Here is the query I typed up manually:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o
LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.[OrderId] = o.[Id]
LEFT JOIN  [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.[Id] = oi.[ProductId]
WHERE p.[ManufacturerId] = 'mid'
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @OrderId INT = 0,
    @CustomerId INT = 0,
    @ProductId INT = 0,
    @WarehouseId INT = 0,
    @BillingCountryId INT = 0,
    @PaymentMethodSystemName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @OrderStatusId INT = 0,
    @PaymentStatusId INT = 0,
    @ShippingStatusId INT = 0,
    @BillingEmail NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingFirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingLastName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ManCode NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @Current BIT = NULL,
    @ShippingMethod NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CreatedFromUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @PageIndex INT = 0, 
    @PageSize INT = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #TempTotal (RowNum INT IDENTITY(1,1), id INT);
    CREATE INDEX #IK_temp ON #TempTotal (RowNum);

    INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
        SELECT o.[Id]
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[Address] a ON a.Id = o.BillingAddressId 
                                           AND (COALESCE(@BillingEmail, '') <> ''
                                                OR COALESCE(@BillingFirstName, '') <> ''
                                                OR COALESCE(@BillingLastName, '') <> '')
        /* LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.OrderId = o.Id 
                                                 AND (COALESCE(@ManCode,'') <> '')
        LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.Id = oi.ProductId 
                                           AND (COALESCE(@ManCode, '') <> '')*/
    WHERE (@BillingEmail IS NULL OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
      AND (@BillingFirstName IS NULL OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
      AND (@BillingLastName IS NULL OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)
      -- AND (@ManCode IS NULL OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode)


    UNION ALL

    (SELECT * 
     FROM [Test].[dbo].[Product] p
     LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.[OrderId] = o.[Id]
     LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.[Id] = oi.[ProductId]
     WHERE (@ManCode IS NULL OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode))

       AND -- here is error
            o.[Deleted] = 0
       AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)
       AND (o.[CustomerId] = @CustomerId OR @CustomerId = 0)
       AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
       AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS NULL OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)
       AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
       AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
       AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)
       AND ((o.[OrderStatusId] != '40' AND o.[OrderStatusId] != '30' AND ((o.[ShippingStatusId] != '30' OR o.[ShippingStatusId] != '40') AND o.[Printed] = '0' AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] != '30' OR o.[PaymentStatusId] != '35' OR o.[PaymentStatusId]  != '40'))) OR @Current = 0)
       AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
       AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
    ORDER BY 
        o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;

    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound INT 
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex

    -- Return the paged records
    SELECT 
        [Id], [OrderGuid], [StoreId], [CustomerId],
        [BillingAddressId], [ShippingAddressId], 
        [OrderStatusId], [ShippingStatusId],
        [PaymentStatusId], [PaymentMethodSystemName],
        [TaxRates], [OrderTax], [OrderDiscount], [OrderTotal],
        [ShippingMethod], [CustomValuesXml], [Deleted],
        [CreatedOnUtc], [EditedStatusId],
        [WarehouseId], [PrintedOnUtc]
    FROM
        [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
    WHERE
        ord.[Id] IN (SELECT id FROM #TempTotal tt)
    ORDER BY 
        ord.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC
        OFFSET @PageLowerBound ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    --total records
    SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(*) FROM #TempTotal;

    DROP TABLE #TempTotal
END
```

I'm not sure if `UNION ALL` is what I need but I feel like it is. I also tried the left joins which are commented out but didn't have any luck there.

Also here is a screenshot of the error at the AND statement.

[image]

Anyone able to help me here?

Comment: You have to select the same columns in all parts of the `union all` you appear to be selecting `id` in the first part and `*` in the second. Change the second to `id` probably?

Comment: @DaleK I added the image of the error at the bottom of my question. But it's also handy to know what you mentioned

Comment: You've got too many brackets, you don't need a bracket around the second query in your union i.e. `UNION ALL (select * from` shouldn't have a bracket (and the matching one needs to be removed as well).

Comment: Your query is completed here with bracket:   (select * from [Test].[dbo].[Product] p

        LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.[OrderId] = o.[Id]
        LEFT JOIN  [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.[Id] = oi.[ProductId]
        WHERE (@ManCode IS null OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode)) and then use AND so..

Comment: @DaleK That error is gone now thanks, but I don't think I can use ```UNION ALL``` then because the product table does not have the order id column

Comment: Yeah I don't know your full logic, but its going to get complicated to try and union 2 queries but still page it. An option it to extend the #temp table to have id's from your Order table, and another column with id's from the product table, then using some logic determine which results to return, then return a union of orders and products where the ids are in the temp table if that makes sense.

Comment: @DaleK if your interested I figured it out, check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out, I needed to use a select statement with a left join which is dependent on the @ManCode parameter not being null.

Paging still works fine too, without having to add extra temp tables :)

Here is how I did it:

```
AND (@ManCode IS null OR EXISTS (
    SELECT [OrderId], [ManufacturerId] FROM [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi with (NOLOCK)
    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Product] p on p.ManufacturerId = oi.ManufacturerId
    WHERE oi.OrderId = o.Id AND p.[ManufacturerId] = '' + @ManCode + ''))
```

So now my full updated stored procedure looks like so:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @OrderId INT = 0,
    @CustomerId INT = 0,
    @ProductId INT = 0,
    @WarehouseId INT = 0,
    @BillingCountryId INT = 0,
    @PaymentMethodSystemName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @OrderStatusId INT = 0,
    @PaymentStatusId INT = 0,
    @ShippingStatusId INT = 0,
    @BillingEmail NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingFirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @BillingLastName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ManCode NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @Current BIT = NULL,
    @ShippingMethod NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CreatedFromUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @PageIndex INT = 0, 
    @PageSize INT = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #TempTotal (RowNum INT IDENTITY(1,1), id INT);
    CREATE INDEX #IK_temp ON #TempTotal (RowNum);

    INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
        SELECT o.[Id]
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[Address] a ON a.Id = o.BillingAddressId 
                                           AND (COALESCE(@BillingEmail, '') <> ''
                                                OR COALESCE(@BillingFirstName, '') <> ''
                                                OR COALESCE(@BillingLastName, '') <> '')

    WHERE (@BillingEmail IS NULL OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
      AND (@BillingFirstName IS NULL OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
      AND (@BillingLastName IS NULL OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)


    AND (@ManCode IS null OR EXISTS (
        SELECT [OrderId], [ManufacturerId] FROM [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi with (NOLOCK)
        LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Product] p on p.ManufacturerId = oi.ManufacturerId
        WHERE oi.OrderId = o.Id AND p.[ManufacturerId] = '' + @ManCode + ''))

       AND
            o.[Deleted] = 0
       AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)
       AND (o.[CustomerId] = @CustomerId OR @CustomerId = 0)
       AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
       AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS NULL OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)
       AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
       AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
       AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)
       AND ((o.[OrderStatusId] != '40' AND o.[OrderStatusId] != '30' AND ((o.[ShippingStatusId] != '30' OR o.[ShippingStatusId] != '40') AND o.[Printed] = '0' AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] != '30' OR o.[PaymentStatusId] != '35' OR o.[PaymentStatusId]  != '40'))) OR @Current = 0)
       AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
       AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
    ORDER BY 
        o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;

    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound INT 
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex

    -- Return the paged records
    SELECT 
        [Id], [OrderGuid], [StoreId], [CustomerId],
        [BillingAddressId], [ShippingAddressId], 
        [OrderStatusId], [ShippingStatusId],
        [PaymentStatusId], [PaymentMethodSystemName],
        [TaxRates], [OrderTax], [OrderDiscount], [OrderTotal],
        [ShippingMethod], [CustomValuesXml], [Deleted],
        [CreatedOnUtc], [EditedStatusId],
        [WarehouseId], [PrintedOnUtc]
    FROM
        [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
    WHERE
        ord.[Id] IN (SELECT id FROM #TempTotal tt)
    ORDER BY 
        ord.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC
        OFFSET @PageLowerBound ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    --total records
    SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(*) FROM #TempTotal;

    DROP TABLE #TempTotal
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @OrderId int = 0,
    @CustomerId int = 0,
    @ProductId int = 0,
    @WarehouseId int = 0,
    @BillingCountryId int = 0,
    @PaymentMethodSystemName nvarchar(max) = null,
    @OrderStatusId int = 0,
    @PaymentStatusId int = 0,
    @ShippingStatusId int = 0,
    @BillingEmail nvarchar(max) = null,
    @BillingFirstName nvarchar(max) = null,
    @BillingLastName nvarchar(max) = null,
    @ManCode nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Current bit = null,
    @ShippingMethod nvarchar(max) = null,
    @CreatedFromUtc datetime = null,
    @CreatedToUtc datetime = null,
    @PageIndex int = 0, 
    @PageSize int = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords int = null OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    create table #TempTotal (RowNum int identity(1,1), id int);
    create index #IK_temp on #TempTotal (RowNum);

    INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
        SELECT o.[Id]
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o with (NOLOCK)

    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Address] a on a.Id = o.BillingAddressId and (
        coalesce(@BillingEmail,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingFirstName,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingLastName,'') <> ''
    )
    /*LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi on oi.OrderId = o.Id and (
        coalesce(@ManCode,'') <> ''
    )
    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Product] p on p.Id = oi.ProductId and (
        coalesce(@ManCode,'') <> ''
    )*/
    WHERE (@BillingEmail IS null OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
    AND (@BillingFirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
    AND (@BillingLastName IS null OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)
    --AND (@ManCode IS null OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode)


    UNION ALL
    select oi.[Id] from [Test].[dbo].[Product] p

        LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.[OrderId] = o.[Id]
        LEFT JOIN  [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.[Id] = oi.[ProductId]
        WHERE (@ManCode IS null OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode)

    AND -- here is error
        o.[Deleted] = 0

    AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)

    AND (o.[CustomerId] = @CustomerId OR @CustomerId = 0)

    AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)

    AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS null OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)

    AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
    AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
    AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)

    AND ((o.[OrderStatusId] != '40' AND o.[OrderStatusId] != '30' AND ((o.[ShippingStatusId] != '30' OR o.[ShippingStatusId] != '40') AND o.[Printed] = '0' AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] != '30' OR o.[PaymentStatusId] != '35' OR o.[PaymentStatusId]  != '40'))) OR @Current = 0)

    AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
    AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')

    ORDER BY o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;

    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex

    -- Return the paged records
    select [Id]
      ,[OrderGuid]
      ,[StoreId]
      ,[CustomerId]
      ,[BillingAddressId]
      ,[ShippingAddressId]
      ,[OrderStatusId]
      ,[ShippingStatusId]
      ,[PaymentStatusId]
      ,[PaymentMethodSystemName]
      ,[TaxRates]
      ,[OrderTax]
      ,[OrderDiscount]
      ,[OrderTotal]
      ,[ShippingMethod]
      ,[CustomValuesXml]
      ,[Deleted]
      ,[CreatedOnUtc]
      ,[EditedStatusId]
      ,[WarehouseId]
      ,[PrintedOnUtc]
    from [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
    where ord.[Id] in (
      select id
      from #TempTotal tt
    )
    ORDER BY ord.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC
    OFFSET @PageLowerBound ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    --total records
    select @TotalRecords = count(*) from #TempTotal;

    DROP TABLE #TempTotal
END
```

Comment: This gives me error ```The multi-part identifier "p.ManufacturerId" could not be bound.```

Comment: Check your product table have this column?? you have use this column here so.....:select oi.[Id] from [Test].[dbo].[Product] p

        LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.[OrderId] = o.[Id]
        LEFT JOIN  [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.[Id] = oi.[ProductId]
        WHERE (@ManCode IS null OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode

Comment: Yeah it definitely has that column

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @OrderId int = 0,
    @CustomerId int = 0,
    @ProductId int = 0,
    @WarehouseId int = 0,
    @BillingCountryId int = 0,
    @PaymentMethodSystemName nvarchar(max) = null,
    @OrderStatusId int = 0,
    @PaymentStatusId int = 0,
    @ShippingStatusId int = 0,
    @BillingEmail nvarchar(max) = null,
    @BillingFirstName nvarchar(max) = null,
    @BillingLastName nvarchar(max) = null,
    @ManCode nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Current bit = null,
    @ShippingMethod nvarchar(max) = null,
    @CreatedFromUtc datetime = null,
    @CreatedToUtc datetime = null,
    @PageIndex int = 0, 
    @PageSize int = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords int = null OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    create table #TempTotal (RowNum int identity(1,1), id int);
    create index #IK_temp on #TempTotal (RowNum);

    INSERT INTO #TempTotal ([id])
        SELECT o.[Id]
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o with (NOLOCK)

    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Address] a on a.Id = o.BillingAddressId and (
        coalesce(@BillingEmail,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingFirstName,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@BillingLastName,'') <> ''
    )
    /*LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi on oi.OrderId = o.Id and (
        coalesce(@ManCode,'') <> ''
    )
    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Product] p on p.Id = oi.ProductId and (
        coalesce(@ManCode,'') <> ''
    )*/
    WHERE (@BillingEmail IS null OR a.[Email] = @BillingEmail)
    AND (@BillingFirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] = @BillingFirstName)
    AND (@BillingLastName IS null OR a.[LastName] = @BillingLastName)
    --AND (@ManCode IS null OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode)


    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        select * from [Test].[dbo].[Product] p

        LEFT JOIN [Test].[dbo].[OrderItem] oi ON oi.[OrderId] = o.[Id]
        LEFT JOIN  [Test].[dbo].[Product] p ON p.[Id] = oi.[ProductId]
        WHERE (@ManCode IS null OR p.[ManufacturerId] = @ManCode)
    )O

    WHERE -- here is error (Here Procdure Can't Findout the object  O) ---So, take 'O' Object Outside........
       o.[Deleted] = 0

    AND (o.[Id] = @OrderId OR @OrderId = 0)

    AND (o.[CustomerId] = @CustomerId OR @CustomerId = 0)

    AND (o.[WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)

    AND (@PaymentMethodSystemName IS null OR o.[PaymentMethodSystemName] = @PaymentMethodSystemName)

    AND (o.[OrderStatusId] = @OrderStatusId OR @OrderStatusId = 0)
    AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] = @PaymentStatusId OR @PaymentStatusId = 0)
    AND (o.[ShippingStatusId] = @ShippingStatusId OR @ShippingStatusId = 0)

    AND ((o.[OrderStatusId] != '40' AND o.[OrderStatusId] != '30' AND ((o.[ShippingStatusId] != '30' OR o.[ShippingStatusId] != '40') AND o.[Printed] = '0' AND (o.[PaymentStatusId] != '30' OR o.[PaymentStatusId] != '35' OR o.[PaymentStatusId]  != '40'))) OR @Current = 0)

    AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
    AND o.[CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')

    ORDER BY o.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;

    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex

    -- Return the paged records
    select [Id]
      ,[OrderGuid]
      ,[StoreId]
      ,[CustomerId]
      ,[BillingAddressId]
      ,[ShippingAddressId]
      ,[OrderStatusId]
      ,[ShippingStatusId]
      ,[PaymentStatusId]
      ,[PaymentMethodSystemName]
      ,[TaxRates]
      ,[OrderTax]
      ,[OrderDiscount]
      ,[OrderTotal]
      ,[ShippingMethod]
      ,[CustomValuesXml]
      ,[Deleted]
      ,[CreatedOnUtc]
      ,[EditedStatusId]
      ,[WarehouseId]
      ,[PrintedOnUtc]
    from [Test].[dbo].[Order] ord
    where ord.[Id] in (
      select id
      from #TempTotal tt
    )
    ORDER BY ord.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC
    OFFSET @PageLowerBound ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;

    --total records
    select @TotalRecords = count(*) from #TempTotal;

    DROP TABLE #TempTotal
END
```

Note:- (Here Procdure Can't Findout the object  O) ---So, take 'O' Object Outside........If can't find out object (alias) ...so it will not work in where condition......

Comment: I'm getting this error now ```Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.``` at this statement ```AND
  o.[Deleted] = 0```

Comment: So...i changed that syntax....with..WHERE -- here is error o.[Deleted] = 0 ...so i take this object outside...then it will not giving any error..

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer :) Thanks for the help